# To whom does each of these wands belong?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore, magical-items, object-identification

### To whom does each of these wands belong?

[image: a rack full of wands]

Note: inspired by [this meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8136/3267)

Comment: "Hmm," said Olivander, "your perfect wand appears to have a skull on the handle, little boy. You'd think that'd be a red flag for me, but nope! Enjoy it!"

Comment: @MacCooper I've thought like that too - maybe they get them somewhere else, carve into them without damaging them or add bits to them? A few are like it - even that thorn one would look a bit bizarre if it 'chose' a little 11-year-old Hufflepuff girl!

Comment: FYI, this post is attracting flags, and spam flags automatically come with downvotes. You may wish to edit it to make absolutely clear that the final paragraph is a joke.

Comment: Shameless plug @ibid

Comment: @CreationEdge it was a joke/shameless ripoff of the linked meta post. Not an advertisement.

Comment: @ibid We keep getting spam flags over and over, so I'm editing out the joke part. It's not an ad, but the joke isn't worth all these flags. Please do not edit it back in.

Comment: @null you could probably leave in the first half of it. I'd imagine it's just the second part which raises the flags.

Comment: The image included in this question appears to be copyrighted. The copyright/trademark notice has been altered/defaced and no reference to the original source of the image has been included in the question.  The original source appears to be: [here](http://www.noblecollection.com/ItemImages/Large/PLQ%20HP%208010.jpg).

Comment: @Makyen The question as posted had a link to the full picture. That part has been edited out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Left to right: Death Eater (known as the swirl), Narcissa Malfoy, Tonks, Death Eater (thorn), Mundungus Fletcher, Alecto Carrow, Death Eater (skull), Rufus Scrimgeour, Voldemort, Slughorn.

Comment: Do I win a prize? I didn't cheat you know! I've become disturbingly expert on wands over the years... [Should I have said that?? Should I have worded it that way!?]

Comment: Why would I want a wand when my existing one is in perfect condition.. Ollivander himself said so yesterday when I paid him a casual visit??